# Need Help in Building a Query Expression in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I recently started using Laravel and got stuck on a query. I'm working on a Tasks App where the user completes different tasks posted by admin.

I want to get only those tasks that are not completed by the login user. when a user completes a task I have a 3rd table completed_tasks where both user_id and task_id stored.

This is how my tables look like:

**user table** (default table created by Laravel auth)
attributes: id,name,email,password

**task table**
attributes: id,name,description

**Completed_task table**
attributes: id, user_id,task_id

I tried using belongsToMany relation between user and tasks using completed_task table as a pivot

Relationship function in users model

```php
public function tasks(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Task', 'completed_task', 'user_id','task_id');
}
```

By using this function I'm getting all tasks that are completed by the login user but I want to get tasks that are not completed by the login user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

```
$tasks = Tasks::whereNotIn('id', function($query) {
        $query->select('task_id')
        ->from('completed_task')
        ->where('user_id', '=', auth()->user()->id);
})->get();
```

This should give you all the task that the logged user has not completed yet (please check the table and the fields names)

Answer (score 0):

All model function looks like this :

**User.php**

```
// A user has many tasks
public function tasks(){
  return $this->hasMany(Task::class);
}
```

**Task.php**

```
// A Task belongs to User
public function users(){
  return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

// A task has a completed status
public function completed(){
  return $this->hasOne(Completed::class);
}
```

**Completed.php**

```
// A Completed status belongs to a Task
public function tasks(){
  return $this->belongsTo(Task::class);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Talha for the answer but the first one solved my problem